# How do I create a fixed navigation bar using md-toolabr in vue material?

Tags: vue.js, material-design, vue-material

I want to create a fixed to nav bar using the vue material framework. How do I do that?

```
<md-whiteframe md-elevation = "3" class = "main-toolbar">



    <md-toolbar class = "flex: 1">



    </md-toolbar>


  </md-whiteframe>
```

I began with this outline but I cannot seem to make it fixed no matter what I do.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add sticky positioning from css. See this codepen for an example: https://codepen.io/aprouja1/pen/awKavJ

```
#toolbar{
    position:sticky;
    top:1px;
}
```

Comment: What I want is that when I scroll the page the navigation bar does not scroll with the page, it remains fixed at the top. This position : sticky does not do that.

Comment: I am using safari.

Comment: Try this one. Added in the webkit style for safari: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/awjbwz

Answer (score 0):

You can use default css like:

```
.main-toolbar {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
```